# Check out Mobile Development Discussions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I’m Sasha, a community manager who works primarily with the Stack Overflow site. On SO, we’ve recently launched [an experimental “Discussions” feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) within several collectives including [the new Mobile Development Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev?tab=overview).

**I am posting here for a few reasons:**

- To invite and encourage your participation in the [Discussions space
  of the Mobile Development
  Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions)
  on Stack Overflow. There is no rep requirement to post or reply
  there, and [the
  guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines)
  allow for a wide range of post types.
- To invite your input on how this community has handled subjective content about Android development and related topics here on this
  site. What has worked well, and what have you struggled with?
- To invite your ongoing collaboration around the evolution of the Discussions concept in general. As venues for building subcommuntiy around a specific topic, both Collectives and Discussions share goals with the Android Enthusiasts community. We’d love to hear your thoughts about the potential benefits, risks, and opportunities that you see ahead.

**Feel free to provide input on this post, or on [our MSO post about this new collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426649/new-collective-mobile-development-scope-community-and-questions).**

We look forward to hearing your thoughts, questions, and ideas.